# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'.

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am trying to migrate our application to use Spring 4 features. So I am slowly trying to **remove XML config** (web.xml, applicationContext.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml) and **replace with Java annotations**. I spent lot of time on this problem, I could not find a solution in stackoverflow also. I am getting the below error:

**org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - [] [line number - 1136] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WP/xhStatus] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'.**
**POST request for "http://localhost:8080/WP/xhStatus" resulted in 404 (null); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null**

From this error message, I tried to see if **PageNotFound** available in Spring API package **org.springframework.web.servlet** at the below URL, but no such class or interface available in that package:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/package-summary.html

I just **added** below two classes **WebAppInitializer.java** & **WebConfig.java** and **removed** some code from **web.xml** and **dispatcher-servlet.xml**.

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
package com.mycompany.wp.web.config;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.setConfigLocations("com.mycompany.wp.web.config.WebConfig");
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(applicationContext));

    servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));
    dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
package com.mycompany.wp.web.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.mycompany.wp")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class); 
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
   registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

I **removed** this part from **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And also I **removed** the below part from **dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.wp"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Now **dispatcher-servlet.xml** has only one entry:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I still have all XML files (web.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml & applicationContext.xml) in my application as they still have some other info. But, there are no changes in applicationContext.xml.

I am trying to call a REST service (Spring MVC Controller) with the request mapping as **/xhStatus**, which I did not change anything. Earlier, my REST service was reachable at the URL mentioned above, but now I can't reach.

Before moving to Java configurations, my application used to work well with XML configuration. Probably, DispatcherServlet is not able to find my Spring Controller.

It would be great if someone can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I made a mistake in **WebAppInitializer.java**

I used:

```
applicationContext.setConfigLocations("com.mycompany.wp.web.config.WebConfig");
```

Now I replaced that line with:

```
applicationContext.register(com.mycompany.wp.web.config.WebConfig.class);
```

It worked fine.